# NPM Run Start / Local Host is not loading and making my computer very slow

Tags: npm, browser, localhost

I am developing a react app, when I run `npm run start` it will not respond in the browser. (this only started happening last night, and only with this specific app. All my other projects work fine)

In windows terminal it shows a successful compile with no errors, but the `localhost:3000` browser (after loading for 5 mins) shows an alert window, and it makes my computer very slow.

I uninstalled react-spring, which was the latest dependency I had installed, but it made no difference.

Any ideas or any additional info I should provide?

[`package.json`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lzq8z.png)